# What do parentheses do after a class is called?

Tags: class, python-3.x, pygame

I have been trying to make a simple player class that contains all of the important player functions in python. I was just getting into the pygame module, when I noticed a class used parentheses. I took the time to learn what a class does in python, but, couldn't find why parentheses are used after for a class. Here is my main code.

```
class plr(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        plr.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20,20))
        self.image.fill(black)
```

Any explanations?

Comment: Which parentheses in your example are you asking about? The `(pygame.sprite.Sprite)` in the `class` statement are around the base class. The double parentheses in `pygame.Surface((20,20))` is making a call (the outer parentheses) with a 2-tuple as the single argument (the inner parentheses).

Comment: `(pygame.sprite.Sprite)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses at the end of the line in a `class` statement surround the base classes of the class you're defining. In the common case, there's just one base class (which may be `object` if no other base class is needed). In Python 3, you can omit the base class and `object` will be used by default, but you should always explicitly name `object` (or some subclass) as a base in Python 2, or you'll get an "old-style" class which is something you probably don't want. (Old style classes are quite thoroughly obsolete and not worth learning about if you're new to Python. They don't exist any more in Python 3.)

Specifying a base class lets your new class inherit methods and other behavior from the base class. Inheritance is a key part of Object Oriented Programming, so you'll probably encounter it quite a bit!

In your specific example, the `plr` class is inheriting from `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. That means you can call `Sprite` methods on instances of `plr`, and they'll usually just work. You can override some of them, if you want to customize your object's behavior.

I do see an error in your code. The `__init__` method you've written will recurse infinitely, since it calls `plr.__init__`, which is itself! You probably wanted it to call `pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__`, which is overriding. You can make that call either with the long name I mentioned above, or by using `super` (which is nicer). Try:

```
class plr(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(plr, self).__init__()
        ...
```

Comment: Explained well. The code I used by the way was incorrect, but I changed it after I posted the question